# JavaScript with WebBrowser control C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Recently I've been running into issues with the Web-browser control in C#.

Navigating to web pages with JavaScript implemented in them makes the WebBrowser crash - It claims there is a syntax error in JS code that is in that webpage.
( It provides the line and what char is the error in so i went to see what caused the error ).

example for an error :

```
  function validate_fen(fen) {
    var errors = {
       0: 'No errors.',
       1: 'FEN string must contain six space-delimited fields.',
       2: '6th field (move number) must be a positive integer.',
       3: '5th field (half move counter) must be a non-negative integer.',
       4: '4th field (en-passant square) is invalid.',
       5: '3rd field (castling availability) is invalid.',
       6: '2nd field (side to move) is invalid.',
       7: '1st field (piece positions) does not contain 8 \'/\'-delimited rows.',
       8: '1st field (piece positions) is invalid [consecutive numbers].',
       9: '1st field (piece positions) is invalid [invalid piece].',
      10: '1st field (piece positions) is invalid [row too large].',
    };
```

the line the error is in is 3977 char number 5 or more specifically last line in this code in char 5 ( Which means its probably the last comma , Correct me if I'm wrong ).

more specific code for the error:

```
  10: '1st field (piece positions) is invalid [row too large].',
};
```

Given the fact that other browsers do load the website properly including IE ( I'm aware of the fact that the webBrowser and IE aren't the same ) How will I approach to solving these problems?

**My thoughts were:**

1. Fix the script while running ( if possible )
2. Somehow load the script anyway.

I'm not sure but I think the webBrowser control doesn't load the script if there is an error which causes more errors later on.

How will I approach on making loading a specific webpage successful?
Is it possible to edit the script while in running (The script isn't in the head scetion of the HTML , its on the server)? And if possible , how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to load and fix scripts in C#:**
Copy the non loading script from the website and fix the syntax errors  and copy it to your code.

> Important note: put all of the script's code in a function so you can
>   call it later

Use the following code to add script to site:

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = script;//script is your script which you defined
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

call InvokeScript to the function you created.

If you fixed all the syntax errors it should be fine.